# Mouse Event Troubles in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, mouse

I just started learning JavaScript and I am trying to create a function that does the following steps.

1. Record the x-coordinate of where the user clicks down and holds (onmousedown(?), not onclick).
2. Then for every ±100 units that the mouse moves in the x-direction while the mouse is still clicked down, I want an action to occur (unimportant for this question, but for example, a popup appears).
3. When the user releases the mouse (onmouseup(?)), the function stops keeping track of the user's mouse position and the action stops (if as in the example, popups would no longer pop up)
4. Repeat steps 1-3 if the user clicks down again.

Here is my miserable attempt...

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html >
<body onmousedown="doThing()">
<script type="text/javascript">

//global variable that tracks whether or not mouse is down or up.
var mouseDown = 0;

document.body.onmousedown = function() 
{ 
  ++mouseDown;
}
document.body.onmouseup = function() 
{
  --mouseDown;
}

//displays the state of the mouse on screen. 1 means mouse is down, 0 means mouse is up.
function track()
{
mouseState.innerHTML = mouseDown;
}

//when the mouse moves 100 units in either direction from the location of the initial downclick, a popup appears
function doThing() 
{
    var xPos = window.event.clientX;
    if (mouseDown==1 && ((Math.abs(xPos-window.event.clientX))>100))
        alert("yay");

}

</script>
<div align="center"><span id="mouseState"></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any feedback/help/tips about anything is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I come up with: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8b79J/1/)

```
//global variable that tracks whether or not mouse is down or up.
var mouseDown = 0;
//global variable that tracks where the mouse position when pressed
var firstPos = 0;
document.body.onmousedown = function(event) 
{ 
     mouseDown = 1;
     track();
     firstPos = window.event.clientX;
}
document.body.onmouseup = function(event) 
{
     mouseDown = 0
     track();
     firstPos = 0;
}
document.body.onmousemove = function()
{
    if (mouseDown == 1){
        doThing();
    }
}
document.body.onmouseout = function()
{
   //important because when you click the alert button `onmouseup` won't be triggered
   mouseDown = 0;
}
//displays the state of the mouse on screen. 1 means mouse is down, 0 means mouse is up.
function track()
{
   mouseState.innerHTML = mouseDown;
}

//when the mouse moves 100 units in either direction from the location of the initial downclick, a popup appears
function doThing(event) 
{
    if (mouseDown==1 && ((Math.abs(firstPos-window.event.clientX))>100))
        alert("yay");

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, and you were very quick! Much appreciated!